# SQL like statement "%[^0-9]%" not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table.

```
USER TABLE Columns:
    user_name (varchar)
    age       (int)
    address   (varchar)
    telephone (varchar)
```

I want to seach for user whose address field contains digits.

I tried the following sql statement in MySQL Workbench:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE address LIKE '%[^0-9]%';
```

However, it did not work. Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     user
WHERE    address REGEXP '.*[^0-9].*'
```

[Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/284e3/2/0) of finding addresses without numbers

Comment: thanks. got it=) but this is strange... when i tried my sql statement in http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_like, it worked.

Comment: @user1140210: `%` isn't a regex character, it's a wildcard. Almost like `s*` when searching for file, SQL's equivalent would be `s%`. And althought `LIKE` can accept certain things that are similar to regex patterns, it's not true regex (that's where `REGEXP` comes in).

Answer (score 5):

You should remove the `^` character from the brackets:

`LIKE '%[0-9]%'`

It doesn't want to be a regex, it is the `[charlist]` wildcard

Comment: You can actually use ^ in the brackets. See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from user where first_name REGEXP '^[0-9].*'
```

This gives you all records in your user table where the first name starts with numbers 0-9.

Answer (score 0):

```
'%[^0-9]%'
```

Will search for the column that has `%[^0-9]%` as  text

It won't do a Regex on it

Try

```
'.[^0-9].'   // That performs regex
```